# How to Change URL in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-status-code-404

I have to change `www.sample.com/users/user/username` to `www.sample.com/username`, but when I go to  `sitename/username` it displays a 404 page. I've tried to route, and `uri->segment`, but I can't get this to work. Please help me with this issue!

Answer (score 3):

Add this line to your `config/routes.php` file.

```
$route['(:any)'] = "users/user/$1";
```

Note that if you do this, you'll have to manually add exceptions for other controllers/actions to work.  So if you have a posts controller, your routes file is now:

```
$route['posts'] = "posts";
$route['posts/(:any)'] = "posts/$1";
$route['(:any)'] = "users/user/$1";
```

And you'll have to do this for every controller/action you have that's not users/user.  You would also have to prevent usernames from being the same names as your other controllers/actions also.

Answer (score 0):

In your `system/application/config/routes.php`, add this:

```
$route['^(?!<otherController1>|<otherController2>).*'] = "users/user/$1";
```

Please note that you need to replace the `<otherController1>|<otherController1>` with actual names of your other actual controllers, like:

```
$route['^(?!welcome|post).*'] = "users/user/$1";
```

And because you wouldn't want the other methods of your Users controller to collide with the usernames, we need to route all the other Users controller methods.  For example:

```
$route['user/subscribe']            = "user/subscribe";
$route['user/username_exists']      = "user/username_exists";
$route['user/email_exists']         = "user/email_exists";
$route['user/signup']               = "user/signup";
```